# firebase не присылает смс на конкретный мобильный оператор!

Tags: java, android, firebase

Привет всем, писал приложение на андроид с firebase. Сделал аутентификацию через номер телефона. С моим оператором смс работает на отлично, но если я пытаюсь прислать смс на Билайн симку моего друга, то ничего не выходит, и смс не присылает. (Я проверил у всех операторов и казус только у билайна).

Как мне быть, ведь бесплатные 10000 смс предоставляет только firebase, и тем более много чего помимо аутентификации уже реализовано в приложении через firebase.

Неужели у всех кто разрабатывает на firebase такие же проблемы. Тот же самый viber который на firebase отлично работает с билайном, как быть? Можно ли решить эту проблему? Или есть аналоги?

Comment: [Почитайте](https://habrahabr.ru/company/everydaytools/blog/329282/) и подумайте, уверены ли Вы в своей архитектуре?

Comment: Может у Вашего друга введен запрет на прием SMS из Интернета?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Я уверен в написанном коде,протестил его более чем на 10 устройствах с разными операторами,везде отработало,кроме билайна, и у тех телефонов нету запрета на смс

Comment: Т.е. Вы проверили более двух сим-карт билайна?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Да,даже 4 сим карт билайна.Вообще в голову не лезет как такое возможно,все остальные операторы ловят смску,а билайн нет,штооо?

Comment: Получилось решить эту проблему? у меня точно такая же проблема с Beeline

Comment: Такая же проблема, не приходят СМС от Firebase Auth именно на Билайн. Никаких ограничений на телефоне нет. На номера всех других операторов СМС приходят. В поддержке Билайна сказали, что на их стороне проблем нет. Решение данной проблемы так и не найдено?

Comment: Пытался звонить в Билайн, никто не может помочь с данной проблемой. Полгода назад все работало без проблем. Сейчас же на 5 из 5 тестовых номеров Билайна код не пришёл.

Answer (score 1):

Есть решение! Проблема в том, что ты должен заключить Договор с оператором Beeline для того, чтобы пользователи Beeline могли получать СМС уведомление.